Extract span value
I feel like I'm close, but after hours of no progress I'm trying here.
I want to scrape span values and assign them to a variable or list for further processing.
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

r=requests.get('https://www.finn.no/car/used/search.html?exterior_colour=6&exterior_colour=13&exterior_colour=14&location=22046&model=1.8078.2000555&q=Long+range&stored-id=75430241')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 

finn=soup.find("div", class_="mb-8 flex justify-between whitespace-nowrap font-bold")
for i in finn:
    print(i.text)

OUTPUT: 
2024
10 200 km
517 129 kr

So I get the values I want from the first search result, but I'm struggling to assign them to a variable or list. I also want to do the same for the rest of the search results, but if I use "find_all" the data output looks different:
OUTPUT: 
202410 200 km517 129 kr
202336 800 km499 999 kr
202237 500 km429 900 kr
202215 000 km460 000 kr
202331 700 km449 000 kr
202234 000 km427 129 kr
202247 000 km456 129 kr
202319 185 km497 129 kr
202247 500 km429 000 kr
202182 000 km397 129 kr
202419 200 km482 129 kr
20246 100 km537 129 kr
202224 000 km469 000 kr


"I'm struggling to assign them to a variable or list". What exactly do you mean? Adding data to any variable type in Python is a simple assignment, or call to one of the class's methods, such as add, append etc..

I think that's expected behaviour? Can you provide the code you use with find_all so that we can test it by ourselves?

If we assume you just put find_all in place of find, this is expected, as according to the doc find_all returns a list of results so in your for loop each value of i will be a full line.

You were indeed quite close. Use find_all() to retrieve all matching div elements with the class mb-8 flex justify-between whitespace-nowrap font-bold like this
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.finn.no/car/used/search.html?exterior_colour=6&exterior_colour=13&exterior_colour=14&location=22046&model=1.8078.2000555&q=Long+range&stored-id=75430241'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

listings = soup.find_all("div", class_="mb-8 flex justify-between whitespace-nowrap font-bold")

car_data = []

for listing in listings:
    spans = listing.find_all('span')
    if spans:  
        car_info = [span.text.strip() for span in spans]
        car_data.append(car_info)



df = pd.DataFrame(car_data, columns=["Year", "Mileage", "Price"])
print(df)

which gives
    Year    Mileage       Price
0   2024  10 200 km  517 129 kr
1   2023  36 800 km  499 999 kr
2   2022  37 500 km  429 900 kr
3   2022  15 000 km  460 000 kr
4   2023  31 700 km  449 000 kr
5   2022  34 000 km  427 129 kr
6   2022  47 000 km  456 129 kr
7   2023  19 185 km  497 129 kr
8   2022  47 500 km  429 000 kr
9   2021  82 000 km  397 129 kr
10  2024  19 200 km  482 129 kr
11  2024   6 100 km  537 129 kr
12  2022  24 000 km  469 000 kr

If you want the headers in Swedish (assumed from the kr)
df = pd.DataFrame(car_data, columns=["År", "Körsträcka", "Pris"])


Create nested lists by find spans and assign them to big list out, last pass to DataFrame constructor:
finn=soup.find_all("div", 
                   class_="mb-8 flex justify-between whitespace-nowrap font-bold")

out = []
for i in finn:
    out.append([j.text for j in i.find_all('span')])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Year','Km','Price'])
print (df)
    Year         Km       Price
0   2024  10 200 km  517 129 kr
1   2023  36 800 km  499 999 kr
2   2022  37 500 km  429 900 kr
3   2022  15 000 km  460 000 kr
4   2023  31 700 km  449 000 kr
5   2022  34 000 km  427 129 kr
6   2022  47 000 km  456 129 kr
7   2023  19 185 km  497 129 kr
8   2022  47 500 km  429 000 kr
9   2021  82 000 km  397 129 kr
10  2024  19 200 km  482 129 kr
11  2024   6 100 km  537 129 kr
12  2022  24 000 km  469 000 kr

Or use list comprehension instead loop:
finn=soup.find_all("div", 
                   class_="mb-8 flex justify-between whitespace-nowrap font-bold")

out = [[j.text for j in i.find_all('span')] for i in finn]
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Year','Km','Price'])

Last is possible some text processing - remove spaces, last kmr and convert values to numbers:
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace('\s+', '', regex=True).str.rstrip('krm').astype(int)
print (df)
    Year     Km   Price
0   2024  10200  517129
1   2023  36800  499999
2   2022  37500  429900
3   2022  15000  460000
4   2023  31700  449000
5   2022  34000  427129
6   2022  47000  456129
7   2023  19185  497129
8   2022  47500  429000
9   2021  82000  397129
10  2024  19200  482129
11  2024   6100  537129
12  2022  24000  469000

